# Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API: Can't not find 'graphics' role in autodesk forge derivatives children

Tags: java, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to convert an .rvt file into .svf.
and I am Using java SDK.(Only, Not node.js, C#)

First at all  i have to get derivatives children.

It is my source code for getting derivatives children.

```
ObjectsApi objectsApi = new ObjectsApi();

ApiResponse<BucketObjects> objects = objectsApi.getObjects("test", 100, null, null, forgeOAuth,
        forgeOAuth.getCredentials());

String base64Urn = "";

// iterate each items of the bucket
for (int i = 0; i < objects.getData().getItems().size(); i++) {

    ObjectDetails eachItem = objects.getData().getItems().get(i);

    base64Urn = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(eachItem.getObjectId().getBytes());
}


ObjectDetails eachItem = objects.getData().getItems().get(0);

base64Urn = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(eachItem.getObjectId().getBytes());
ApiResponse<Manifest> manifest = derivativesApi.getManifest(base64Urn, "", forgeOAuth, forgeOAuth.getCredentials());
```

but this is not suitable for getting 'graphics' role.
it provides to me Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase, 3d, some thumbnail

following is result set of manifest.getData()

```
class Manifest {
    urn: dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cDE4MDE3Ni8xODAyMTVfMTAwXzNfQTEwMS5ydnQ
    type: manifest
    progress: complete
    status: success
    hasThumbnail: true
    region: US
    derivatives: [class ManifestDerivative {
        name: 180215_100_3_A101.rvt
        hasThumbnail: true
        outputType: svf
        progress: complete
        status: success
        children: [class ManifestChildren {
            type: resource
            role: Autodesk.CloudPlatform.PropertyDatabase
            guid: 6fac95cb-af5d-3e4f-b943-8a7f55847ff1
            name: null
            phaseNames: null
            viewableID: null
            hasThumbnail: null
            mime: application/autodesk-db
            urn: urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cDE4MDE3Ni8xODAyMTVfMTAwXzNfQTEwMS5ydnQ/output/Resource/model.sdb
            progress: null
            status: success
            resolution: []
            modelGUID: null
            objectIds: []
            messages: null
            camera: []
        }, class ManifestChildren {
            type: geometry
            role: 3d
            guid: 3cb8c807-d232-58e3-31d1-f4f89ad98945
            name: {3D}
            phaseNames: Phase 1
            viewableID: ecda35ed-79db-4c54-8ae1-3bb64e7f3640-000473bc
            hasThumbnail: true
            mime: null
            urn: null
            progress: complete
            status: success
            resolution: []
            modelGUID: null
            objectIds: []
            messages: null
            camera: []
        }]
    }, class ManifestDerivative {
        name: null
        hasThumbnail: null
        outputType: thumbnail
        progress: complete
        status: success
        children: [class ManifestChildren {
            type: resource
            role: thumbnail
            guid: db899ab5-939f-e250-d79d-2d1637ce4565
            name: null
            phaseNames: null
            viewableID: null
            hasThumbnail: null
            mime: image/png
            urn: urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cDE4MDE3Ni8xODAyMTVfMTAwXzNfQTEwMS5ydnQ/output/preview1.png
            progress: null
            status: success
            resolution: [100, 100]
            modelGUID: null
            objectIds: []
            messages: null
            camera: []
        }, class ManifestChildren {
            type: resource
            role: thumbnail
            guid: 3f6c118d-f551-7bf0-03c9-8548d26c9772
            name: null
            phaseNames: null
            viewableID: null
            hasThumbnail: null
            mime: image/png
            urn: urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cDE4MDE3Ni8xODAyMTVfMTAwXzNfQTEwMS5ydnQ/output/preview2.png
            progress: null
            status: success
            resolution: [200, 200]
            modelGUID: null
            objectIds: []
            messages: null
            camera: []
        }, class ManifestChildren {
            type: resource
            role: thumbnail
            guid: 4e751806-0920-ce32-e9fd-47c3cec21536
            name: null
            phaseNames: null
            viewableID: null
            hasThumbnail: null
            mime: image/png
            urn: urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cDE4MDE3Ni8xODAyMTVfMTAwXzNfQTEwMS5ydnQ/output/preview4.png
            progress: null
            status: success
            resolution: [400, 400]
            modelGUID: null
            objectIds: []
            messages: null
            camera: []
        }]
    }]
}
```

the same revit file is working well in C#.

```
{
    "urn": "urn:adsk.viewing:fs.file:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6cDE4MDE3Ni90ZXN0LmR3Zng/output/99c9d5d0-fa02-c7ed-15a9-6a62ec928cd2/0.svf",
    "role": "graphics",
    "mime": "application/autodesk-svf",
    "guid": "87f5601a-158a-10fb-f22a-c828d008e178",
    "type": "resource",
    "status": "success"
}
```

Can i get method to get derivatives children have "role": "graphics", "mime": "application/autodesk-svf"?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply "converting an .rvt file into .svf", you don't have to worry about the structure of the manifest in your Java code at all. Converting a design using the Forge Model Derivative service generates various outputs (thumbnails, 2D sheets, 3D views, property database, etc.), and after that, choosing the desired 2D sheet or 3D view is typically handled by the JavaScript code on the client side.

For example, in this [tutorial](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.viewmodels/blob/java/src/main/webapp/js/ForgeViewer.js#L36) the JavaScript code finds and loads the "default" derivative, but you could also use the [search](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/BubbleNode/#search-propstomatch) method to find all the viewables with specific `role` and/or `mime` values.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer!
But my goal isn't just converting  a .rvt file into .svf.
My Final goal is loading a 3D View in local environment. So that i wanna download all file for loading 3D View in local environment such as .svf, *.json.gz, .sdb extension.
Can i download various outputs (thumbnails, 2D sheets, 3D views, property database, etc.) by the JavaScript code on the client side or java?

Comment: Ah I see. I'm not aware of any options for Java but yes, there are a couple of ways of downloading the entire SVF bundle, for example, by following https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-svf-extractor-nodejs, or using https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils as a command line tool.